# Keytool.exe and jarsigner.exe issues

Tags: java, security, applet, keytool, jarsigner

I have finished a small game in Java and I want to upload it online. I have an HTML file that loads it properly, as well as the code being fine. However, I can't use the function

```
File file = new File(System.getenv("appdata") + "\\sniperscreed\\save.dat");
```

If I run it locally in Eclipse it works fine, but if I run it in a browser it says it needs my .jar file to be signed. After following many tutorials, I find that the only way to self-certify is to use these following commands:

```
keytool -genkey hello -alias HeyGuys
jarsigner "C:\my path\myJar.jar" myKeyName
```

None of this works, all it does is say that "keytool" is not a recognizable executable as well as the jarsigner. So I went into the Java JDK folder and copied the files, along with the jli.dll that's required, and now it gives me this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZBof.png

Thanks.

Comment: 1) *"now it gives me this:"*  Type the **text** of it, rather than link to a screenshot! 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer out recently, pretty simple fix actually.

In order to fix the issue, you should have a global variable set to the actual JDK build folder, however I didn't do this. Making an absolute path to the executables works just as well (ex. instead of keysigner.exe, use C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\keytool).

I really hope this helps someone in the future.